# Is it possible to search for same value on multiple columns with Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, orm

I have search query that has many optional parameters and then search word field that searches many columns. Is it possible to use hibernate criteria for this purpose? I need to search many columns with same search word.

Example code (what is not working correctly)

```
if(isNotEmpty(searchWord))
{
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("description", searchWord));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", searchWord));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should not be a problem. But *what exactly*  is not working? While you're at it, you might also want to rename "serachWord" to "searchWord".

Comment: If search word is not included in name AND description column, then it will return no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with using custom sql restrictions, example here:

```
Object[] values = {  }; // values here
Type[] types = {  }; // value types here
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("sql query here", values, types));
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you actually need an OR:

```
Criterion description = Restrictions.like("description", searchWord);
Criterion name = Restrictions.like("name", searchWord);
LogicalExpression orExp = Restrictions.or(description, name);
criteria.add(orExp);
```

Comment: +1 Thanx for this, but it only allows two values in that or, so I used sql restrictions.

Comment: Hi here in the criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("sql query here", values, types)); what I have to pass for types.

Answer (score 2):

by using Disjunction we have add any number of columns and finally add the Disjunction obj to criteria.

```
Disjunction disCriteria = Restrictions.disjunction();
disCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", searchWord));
disCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("description", searchWord));
criteria.add(disCriteria);
```